# Or statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this if condition in JavaScript, at the moment what it does is loads a drop down list when status of a order is ready for despatch. I also want the if condition to work for OR Despatched.

The if condition is below

```
if ($(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val() == "ReadyForDespatch")
```

How do I add a or for this i.e. `|| "Despatched"` is it something like

```
if ($(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val() == "ReadyForDespatch" || "Despatched")
```

Thanks

Comment: Get the values first - `var status = $(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val(); if(status == 'ReadyForDespatch' || status == 'Despatched') { ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide complete condition after the `||`, better would be to store result in a variable and then use it in the if block:

```
var status = $(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val();

if(status == "ReadyForDespatch" || status == "Despatched")
```

Comment: `||` works fine.. Instead, can we use array on it to compare multiple values?

Comment: I would add the brackets too on `if`

Answer (score 3):

Six options:

## 1

```
// KISS solution ;)
var val = $(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val();

if(val == "ReadyForDespatch" || val == "Despatched") {

}
```

## 2

```
// ES6+
if(["ReadyForDespatch", "Despatched"].includes($(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val()))  {

}
```

## 3

```
// ES5+
var val = $(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status")).val();

if(["ReadyForDespatch", "Despatched"].some(someValue => someValue == val))  {

}
```

## 4

```
// ES5+
if(["ReadyForDespatch", "Despatched"].indexOf($(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status")).val()) > -1)  {

}
```

## 5

```
// ES ALL
switch($(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val())
{
       case "ReadyForDespatch":
       case "Despatched":

          break;
}
```

## 6

```
// ES6+
// This is an overkill for 2 elements, but I've added it for the sake of
// showing the wonders of Set collection
if(new Set(["ReadyForDespatch", "Despatched"]).has($(this).closest("td").closest("tr").find("input.pcss-product-order-status").val()) {

}
```

Comment: the `some` and `includes` are part of native js ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Absolutely. `some` is ES5, and `includes` ES6 and above.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad See #4 which is compatible with ES5 too and it's like using `includes`.

Comment: Can you add the details that which is compatible with which ES? that would be appreciated and will be helpful to future visitors

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I did it before you requested it, see my updated answer :D